# visual studio shows c# decimals with different precision

Tags: c#, decimal

While debugging I noticed that visual studio debugger and Console.WriteLine (and also winforms devexpress grids) show decimal variables in different precision/formating. I did not find anything about setting precision on c# decimals. How is the formatting determined under the hood?

The values I saw are:

- 117.8010
- 1095270.0000000000000

Indeed I read [C# decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#838-the-decimal-type) part of specification but it is unclear for me how it relates to different number of zeros in the representation of the number:

> The finite set of values of type decimal are of the form (–1)ᵛ × c × 10⁻ᵉ, where the sign v is 0 or 1, the coefficient c is given by 0 ≤ c < Cmax, and the scale e is such that Emin ≤ e ≤ Emax, where Cmax is at least 1 × 10²⁸, Emin ≤ 0, and Emax ≥ 28. The decimal type does not necessarily support signed zeros, infinities, or NaN’s.

[image: low res]
[image: high ress]

Comment: Why do you care about the precision of the debugger output window? That's just what you see

Comment: `decimal` records precision. `117.8010` and `117.80100` are numerically the same value, but not the same `decimal`. Whether the debugger and/or DevExpress and/or whatever else you're looking at fully represent that precision is another matter.

Comment: @TimSchmelter since the UI (dev express grid) shows a different formating, which now needs to be set manually (which is easy). I just want to know how things work under the hood

Comment: @JeroenMostert this is helpful, can this be inspected or even changed? Are there some kind of rules or documentation?

Comment: The VS managed debugger is one of the least well documented and most black magic ridden pieces of code in existence (at least to the outside world, it might be a little better within Microsoft), so I'd wager not. :P From .NET 7 onwards `decimal` itself exposes the `Scale` property; in prior versions you'd have to inspect the internals.